# How to calculate Gibbs free energy of adsorption at constant temperature with varying pressures

Tags: free-energy, adsorption

I want to calculate the Gibbs free energy of adsorption for an oxidized surface. The literature I consulted used the equations attached to this post. I am trying hard to find my way through. Any idea how to go about it would be deeply appreciated. I am supposed to have a linear plot with pressure as abscissa and delta G as ordinate. [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO the equations you show use too many "$\Delta$" which makes it more confusing. I will hence try to avoid the use of "$\Delta$" in the equations below.

To get the adsorption free energy for the oxidized surface, you need to calculate
\begin{equation}
    G_{\mathrm{ads}} = G_{\mathrm{slab(oxidized)}} - G_{\mathrm{slab}} - N_{\mathrm{O}}\mu_{\mathrm{O}}(T,p)
\tag{1} \label{1}
\end{equation}

To avoid computationally expensive phonon calculations, the common assumption is that the free energy corrections for the surface and the oxidized surface will cancel out by $G_{\mathrm{slab(oxidized)}} - G_{\mathrm{slab}}$, except for the vibrational free energy term for the oxygens adsorbed on the surface, $F^{\mathrm{vib}}_{\mathrm{O*}}$. We can then rewrite the equation as
\begin{equation}
    G_{\mathrm{ads}} = E_{\mathrm{slab(oxidized)}} + F^{\mathrm{vib}}_{\mathrm{O*}} - E_{\mathrm{slab}} - N_{\mathrm{O}}\mu_{\mathrm{O}}(T,p) \tag{2} \label{2}
\end{equation}
where $E$ represents the electronic energy which can be calculated by e.g. DFT.

In general, we can calculate $F^{\mathrm{vib}}$ by
\begin{equation}
F^{\mathrm{vib}} = E^{\mathrm{ZPE}} + \int_0^TC_V\mathrm{d}T - TS
\tag{3} \label{3}
\end{equation}
where $E^{\mathrm{ZPE}}$ is the zero-point energy, $C_V$ is the heat capacity which is separable into translational, rotational, vibrational and electronic parts, $S$ is the entropy which is separable into translational, rotational, vibrational and configurational parts. You can calculate these terms in the harmonic limit using e.g. [`ase.thermochemistry.HarmonicThermo`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/thermochemistry/thermochemistry.html#ase.thermochemistry.HarmonicThermo). Note that this could be expensive if you have high O* coverage. A simplification would be to calculate using only one O* adsorbate, and multiply the single-O* vibrational free energy term by the number of O*.

Next, we can assume the oxidized surface is in equilibrium with the gas phase O$_2$, and calculate $\mu_{\mathrm{O}}(T,p)$ as $\mu_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}(T,p) / 2$. The $\mu_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}(T,p)$ term can then be determined in the ideal gas limit by
\begin{equation}
    \mu_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}(T, p) = E_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}} + \Delta\mu_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}^{0,T} + k_{\mathrm{B}}T\ln(p_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}/p^0) \tag{4} \label{4}
\end{equation}
where $E_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}$ is the electronic energy of the O$_2$ molecule which can be calculated by DFT, $\Delta\mu^{0,T}_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}$ is the chemical potential correction term (including zero-point energy) obtained from vibrational calculations at standard pressure $p^0=1$ atm, $k_{\mathrm{B}}$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $p_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}$ is the fugacity of the gas phase O$_2$.

In general, we can calculate $\Delta\mu^{0,T}$ as
\begin{equation}
\Delta\mu^{0,T} = E^{\mathrm{ZPE}} + \int_0^TC_P\mathrm{d}T - TS \tag{5} \label{5}
\end{equation}
where $C_P = C_V + k_{\mathrm{B}}$ (switching from constant-volume to constant-pressure). These terms can again be calculated by ASE using [`ase.thermochemistry.IdealGasThermo`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/thermochemistry/thermochemistry.html#ase.thermochemistry.IdealGasThermo).

It is not hard to see that the adsorption free energy $G_{\mathrm{ads}}$ is effectively a function of $T$ and $p_{\mathrm{O_2(g)}}$. At constant temperature and various pressures, the expensive terms only need to be calculated once.

Comment: Thank you once again for the rescue. Considering about an earlier answer you gave for the oxidized surface would ase be able to do the calculation for me? If not I have access to a supercomputer can I use DFT to calculate all? I saw in literature some referring to JANAF tables in determining the standard chemical potential in your last equation. Any information about that too?

Comment: Yes you can use ASE to calculate all, but you still need DFT which needs supercomputer. And yes, instead of calculating the standard chemical potential of O$_2$(g) by yourself, you can refer to the [NIST JANAF tables](https://janaf.nist.gov/tables/O-029.html), but there are many other terms that still needs DFT.

Comment: Thanks. I will do phonon calculations to determine the Fvib and use the JANAF table to determine the standard chemical potential. Thank you once again.

Comment: The equation of chemical potential, I mean the last but one. The last term on the right-hand side. Please is it kb or R? I am seeing R everywhere. Any clarification?

Comment: @NanaKofiBoakye They are essentially the same thing. $R = N_{\mathrm A}k_{\mathrm B}$

Comment: @NanaKofiBoakye In the physics field more people use $k_\mathrm{B}$ instead of $R$. If you want literature, see 10.1103/PhysRevB.77.075437 Eq.(5) for example.

Comment: Good paper. Thanks very much.

Comment: The existing chat rooms can be used if this conversations needs more comments.

Comment: @ShaunHan I used vasp to do the phonon calculations. How do I extract the Fvib?

Comment: @NanaKofiBoakye I don't know. I never use VASP to do phonon calculations.

Comment: @ShaunHan Have a look at the following link for me if you can use it to answer my question. Thanks. 

https://vaspkit.com/tutorials.html#adsorbed-molecular-free-energy-correction

Comment: @ShaunHan the above code I pointed outputs the information below after supplying an input temperature.

Temperature (T): 300.0 K
 Zero-point energy E_ZPE   :      72.232 kcal/mol    3.132266 eV
 Thermal correction to U(T):      85.703 kcal/mol    3.716441 eV
 Thermal correction to H(T):      85.703 kcal/mol    3.716441 eV
 Thermal correction to G(T):      66.293 kcal/mol    2.874750 eV
 Entropy S                 :     270.703 J/(mol*K)   0.002806 eV/K
 Entropy contribution T*S  :   81210.770 J/(mol)     0.841691 eV

Since F = U - TS, can I calculate the energy from this?